# Excel: If cell "B" has the same number as cell "A," display the complete number in cell "C."

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

[image: IMAGE SAMPLE HERE]

Please see photo to understand clearly my scenario.

Excel: If cell "B" has the same number as in cell "A," display the complete number in cell "C."

I have tried different functions but look for solution but I have not found any possible solution of what I wanted to happened like using =XLOOKUP, Match and IF. Hope anyone can be give me sample or same scenario. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Do not provide images please. And SHOUTING will not help either.

Comment: @destructioneer I updated it for OP

Comment: Google Sheets and Microsoft Excel each have different feature sets. The [google-sheets] tag description explicitly states _"Do NOT use with [excel]"_ and the [excel] tag description explicitly states _"Do NOT use with other spreadsheet software like [google-sheets]."_ Choose one platform and edit tags appropriately.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like the format of `COMPLETE_ID`s is `INCOMPLETE_ID` + a year. If that is the case, then you can separate the `COMPLETE_ID`s into a year and ID column, then run an XLOOKUP/INDEX+MATCH on the new ID column.

I would share an example, but I tried using the data in the screenshot, but none of the examples in `INCOMPLETE_ID` are in `COMPLETE_ID`

Comment: Hi thank you for your respond and for editing my post this is my first time. I would like to share complete data is it possible here to attached notepad file or any file? Thanks

Comment: yeah maybe put it in a csv file and upload it, or put it in a code block, or put it in a google sheet and share a public link to it

Comment: Great! this is I am currently working https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1S8DZ-LaPES4lYBxmuvdXa2NusZ-VvUOcqeb3NGzteRg/edit#gid=0

Comment: @AlvisCuering see the new sheet in the document

Comment: Yes I see it, this idea really works! thank you so much @Mark!

Comment: no worries! glad I could help. If you want, you can mark the answer correct :-)

Answer (score 1):

*You may also try:*

```js
=map(B2:B,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,ifna(+filter(A:A,search(Σ,A:A)=1)))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Google Sheets, you can use `filter()` and `match()` to get the list of long IDs in column `A2:A` whose first `5` characters match at least one short ID in column `D2:D` like this:

```
=filter(A2:A, match(left(A2:A, 5), to_text(D2:D), 0))
```

See [filter()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093197) and [match()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378).